# The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-standard-2.0

After upgrading some of our class libraries to .NET Standard 2.0, `System.Data.SqlClient` went away and we now need to use `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` in those projects.

However, we are now seeing this error when calling a stored procedure:

> The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects

This worked fine on `System.Data.SqlClient`.

I've looked online and lot of people talk about this error being fixed after simply using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, but since that's what creates my issue I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
 public int GetStuff(long memberId, DateTime start, DateTime end)
 {
     var idParameter = new SqlParameter("@intID", memberId);
     var startMonthParameter = new SqlParameter("@intMonth1", start.Month);
     var endMonthParameter = new SqlParameter("@intMonth2", end.Month);
     var startYearParameter = new SqlParameter("@intYear", start.Year);

     return ExecuteStoreProcedure<int>("sp_GetStuff", idParameter, startMonthParameter, endMonthParameter, startYearParameter);
 }

 private T ExecuteStoreProcedure<T>(string procedureName, params SqlParameter[] sqlParamaters)
 {
     var procedure = $"{procedureName} {string.Join(", ", sqlParamaters.Select(p => p.ParameterName))}";
     var parameters = sqlParamaters.ToArray<object>();

     return Database.SqlQuery<T>(procedure, parameters).First();     
 }
```

Comment: 1) System.Data.SqlClient did not "go away". 2) What do you mean by a null SqlParameter type object. What is the error here?

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient` didn't go away. It still exists as a package. Look at your library's dependencies and see if you're using any packages that depend on it. You might be creating instances of that `SqlParameter` type rather than the one from `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: Are you `using System.Data.SqlClient` instead of the new `using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`?

Comment: Side note, but you can often improve performance and stop certain tricky conversion bugs by setting the explicit DB type when creating your parameters. Instead of just `new SqlParameter("name", value)`, use `new SqlParameter("name", SqlDbType, [optional length/scale] ).Value = value;`

Comment: Side note #2: in case the parameters are in the wrong order you should do `string.Join(", ", sqlParamaters.Select(p => p.ParameterName + " = " + p.ParameterName))`

Comment: @madreflection Thank you, I didn't realize there was a package now!  I only saw the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient one...

Answer (score 0):

Based on @madreflection comment I added the System.Data.SqlClient package instead of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and it fixed my issues for .NET Standard 2.0.  Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: I'm glad that worked, but that wasn't really where I was hoping that would go. `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` is the package that will be getting new features and bug fixes. `System.Data.SqlClient` is there for compatibility and as an upgrade path. You should be using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` if at all possible.

Comment: I would say that the cause for the error was an incomplete upgrade to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.